# Is it possible to sent a string variable into a JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

I am working on a function which allows the price of an order to be automatically calculated based off user inputs into a form. The users will be selecting the "Type" of service they want, and also inputting the "square foot" of an order.

Is the problem because I have attempted to set a string variable to have a intiger value?

When I press the button on the form there is nothing printed on the webpage.

```html
 <form>  
 <select id="type" required>
  <option disabled selected value> Type of service </option>
  <option value="Gardening">Gardening</option>
  <option value="Decorating">Decorating</option>
  <option value="Fencing">Fencing</option>
  <option value="Flooring">Flooring</option>
  <option value="Landscaping">Landscaping</option>
 </select> 

 <input type="number" id="square_ft" placeholder="square_ft">
 
 <button type="submit" onclick="calculatePrice()">Check Price</button>
 </form>

 <p id="price"> </p>
 
  
 <script>
   function calculatePrice() {
   var hours = 4;
   var totalPriceHour = 0;
   var priceHour = 0;
   var priceSquareFt = 0;
   var totalSquareFt = 0;
   var orderTotal = 0;
   var materials = false; 
   
   var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
   var square_ft = document.getElementById("square_ft").value;
   
   
    if (type == Gardening) {
     priceHour = 20;
     priceSquareFt = 3;
     
    } else if (type == Decorating) {
     priceHour = 20;
     priceSquareFt = 3;
    } else if (type == Landscaping) {
     priceHour = 30;
     priceSquareFt = 2;
    } else if (type == Flooring) {
     priceHour = 20;
     priceSquareFt = 2;
    } else (type == Fencing) {
     priceHour = 30;
     priceSquareFt = 3;
    }
    
    totalPriceHour = hours * priceHour;
    totalSquareFt = square_ft * priceSquareFt;
    orderTotal = totalSquareFt + totalPriceHour;
  
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = orderTotal;
   }
  </script>
```

Comment: Your type == expects a string, in it's current format, it's a variable, and undefined.

Comment: So would it work if i just used one "="?

Comment: No, that would set the variable to the value that 'type' has. You'll have to use " ", ' ', or ` ` symbols around your Gardening, Decorating etc so they are interpreted as strings.

Comment: `if (type == "Gardening")` - notice the quotation marks (`"`)

Comment: the double equal is fine (or triple equals for good measure) but your conditional statements should have quotation marks around the expected/tested value: `type === "Fencing"`  Without the quotation marks, the code is expecting some sort of variable named Fencing

Comment: Thank you guys, the code is now working with the quotation marks. That makes sense to me now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the value of an input will return a string so make sure you compare your type variable to a string adding quotes to your validation... also if you put a submit button inside your form this will attempt to send a request to the server..

```js
        function calculatePrice() {
        var hours = 4;
        var totalPriceHour = 0;
        var priceHour = 0;
        var priceSquareFt = 0;
        var totalSquareFt = 0;
        var orderTotal = 0;
        var materials = false; 

        var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
        var square_ft = document.getElementById("square_ft").value;


            if (type == 'Gardening') {
                priceHour = 20;
                priceSquareFt = 3;

            } else if (type == 'Decorating') {
                priceHour = 20;
                priceSquareFt = 3;
            } else if (type == 'andscaping') {
                priceHour = 30;
                priceSquareFt = 2;
            } else if (type == 'Flooring') {
                priceHour = 20;
                priceSquareFt = 2;
            } else if (type == 'Fencing') {
                priceHour = 30;
                priceSquareFt = 3;
            }

            totalPriceHour = hours * priceHour;
            totalSquareFt = square_ft * priceSquareFt;
            orderTotal = totalSquareFt + totalPriceHour;

            document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = orderTotal;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>      
<select id="type" required>
    <option disabled selected value> Type of service </option>
    <option value="Gardening">Gardening</option>
    <option value="Decorating">Decorating</option>
    <option value="Fencing">Fencing</option>
    <option value="Flooring">Flooring</option>
    <option value="Landscaping">Landscaping</option>
</select> 

<input type="number" id="square_ft" placeholder="square_ft">

<button type="button" onclick="calculatePrice()">Check Price</button>
</form>

<p id="price"> </p>
```